# format datetime value in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

i want to format date time value in this format ("yyyy/MM/dd")

below is the code, m using to do so

```
DateTime? date = DateTime.Now;
DateTime? formattedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
Console.WriteLine(formattedDate);
Console.ReadLine();
```

the code work fine but you can see in the above code that i have declared datetime variable as null which in reverse causing the problem

please suggest what i am doing wrong in the above code.

as i am getting the output as this `9/10/2012 12:00:00 AM`

Thanks,
Aaman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that what you call `formattedDate` is actually yet another instance of a DateTime. There's no notion of format inside the native .NET DateTime structure. You can talk about formatting only when you convert it to a string:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string formattedDate = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
Console.WriteLine(formattedDate);
```

or if you want to use a nullable DateTime:

```
DateTime? date = DateTime.Now;
string formattedDate = date.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
Console.WriteLine(formattedDate);
```

But since your question is tagged with `asp.net-mvc-3`, there are other ways to format values. For example using the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute on your view model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

and in your view if you want to display the value of your view model:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Date)
```

or if you want to generate an input field with properly formatted value:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Date)
```

Comment: it is working fine for @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Date) and for @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Date) but when i am binding this to @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Date) then again the same problem

Comment: Yes, that's normal. The DisplayFormat attribute works only with editor/display templates. Why would you want to use TextBoxFor?

Comment: as per requirement i want to show in the textbox...which is also disabled for the user...

Comment: In this case you could write a custom editor template for the DateTime type (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyFormattedDateTime.cshtml`) containing the following: `@Html.TextBox("", string.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", Model), new { @readonly = "readonly" })` and then decorate your view model property with the UIHint attribute: `[UIHint("MyFormattedDateTime")] public DateTime? Date { get; set; }`.